# Adding JsonMessage to RabbitMQ through Ajax Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, rabbitmq

I want to know if anyone of you are adding messages to RabbitMQ through AJax Jquery. I have .Net Helper which adds the same. But I want to know how to do it through Ajax.

All the client apps should log to RabbitMQ , so that Node can read it and process the same and pass the message to some other clients.

Any reference links would be great

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand your question but this might be what you're looking for:
https://github.com/squaremo/rabbit.js

Comment: Hi Daniel , I want to add to rabit mq directly from Client.

Comment: I know there are apis from dotnet and java